# How can I change what this error message says?

Tags: magento2.3, error-message

How would I change the error message here in Magento2 from "Something went wrong while processing your quote. Please try again later." to "Please login in to process your quote."

I can not seem to find the code to change the error message.

[image]

Comment: Please add your custom code here before suggestion I need to check the exact issue. After that I can say the solution

Comment: check your error log..

Comment: You can do it by adding your new text as translation in app/design/frontend/Yourpackage/Yourtheme/i18n/en_US.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the text to the desired error message in this file

> app/design/frontend/Vendor_Theme/Theme_name/i18n/en_US.csv

Comment: Hi, I tried this and thought this worked.  But atlas I did not see the changes in the frontend.  I found the piece of code thought in the Module.  of app/code/Vendor/Name/i18n/en_US.csv. Try to make changes there but the changes did not come through.

Comment: You need to run static content & then cache clean. after changes in file.

Comment: Let me know if it works.